# Positioning images inside of images

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am currently trying to combine icons of flags with a users profile-picture.

For your understanding, I have the following Spritesheet:

[image]

The Icons should be positioned like this:

[image]

I am thinking of a div container/wrapper containing the user-profile-image, and some subdivs with the classes of the icons, is that the best way to do it?

What I have so far (not really useful, as I just placed the icons beneath the userpic using html)

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 instrBox">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center visible-md visible-lg">
         [...]
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center teamBlock">
        <img src="img/team/user.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 pull-left visible-md visible-lg">
        <i class="sprite-team sprite-team-flag_lu"></i>
        <i class="sprite-team sprite-team-flag_fr"></i>
        <i class="sprite-team sprite-team-flag_pt"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.instrBox {
    width: 23%;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}}

.teamBlock .img-responsive {
margin: 0 auto;
}

.sprite-team {
background-image: url("../img/team/sprite-team.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: block;
}

.sprite-team-flag_fr {
    width: 41px;
    height: 20px;
    background-position: -5px -5px;
}
....
```

Currently looks like this, maybe adding a margin-left with negative values?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: it is better if you add what you have already tried.

Comment: `is that the best way to do it?` Do it however it works for you. Opinion-based questions are off-topic for SO.

Comment: @j08691 Sure, but I have not figured out any way yet. Just wanted to know what the easiest would be for this to work on mobile aswell as on pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is in the css background-position. And, I suggest you go with a transparent png so that you don't get the white background when you superimpose the flags over the rounded rectangle.

```css
#container{
 background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez7w1.png);
 width: 134px;
 height: 135px;
 background-position-x: -150px;
}
#container div {
 background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez7w1.png);
    width: 50px;
    height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    right: -110px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    top: 17px;
}
#container div:nth-child(1){
 background-position: -100px 0px;
}
#container div:nth-child(2){
 /*no positioning needed in this example*/
}
#container div:nth-child(3){
 background-position: 0px -32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the user icon image to 'relative', then the flag icons to 'absolute'.

Then set the flag icons position with the 'top, left, right, down" properties.

[For example](https://jsfiddle.net/yte2ew5r/).

HTML

```
<div class="A">
<div class="B"></div>
<div class="C"></div>
<div class="D"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.A {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: gold;
  position: relative;
}

.B { 
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 350px;
}

.C { 
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
position: absolute;
top: 90px;
left: 350px;
}

.D { 
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
position: absolute;
top: 160px;
left: 350px;
}
```